# ORACLE_HOME: command not found

Tags: oracle, bash

> **Hello Everybody**  I have confufrated bash_profile as follow
>
> ```
> # .bash_profile
> Get the aliases and functions if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then     . ~/.bashrc` fi
>
> User specific environment and startup programs PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin export PATH
>
> Oracle Settings TMP=/tmp; export TMP TMPDIR=$TMP; export TMPDIR ORACLE_HOSTNAME=merkez-rac1.localdomain; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
>
> ORACLE_UNQNAME=RAC; export ORACLE_UNQNAME ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle;
> export ORACLE_BASE GRID_HOME=/u01/app/11.2.0/grid; export GRID_HOME
> DB_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/db_1; export DB_HOME
> ORACLE_HOME=$DB_HOME; export ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_SID=RAC1; export
> ORACLE_SID ORACLE_TERM=xterm; export ORACLE_TERM
> BASE_PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH; export BASE_PATH
> PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$BASE_PATH; export PATH
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/JRE:$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib;
> export CLASSPATH
>
>
> if [$USER = "oracle" ] ; then if [ $SHELL= "/bin/ksh" ] ; then
>
> ulimit -p 16384 ulimit -n 65536`enter code here`
>
> else`enter code here` K ulimit -u 16384 -n 65536 fi  fi alias
> gid_env='. /home/oracle/gid_env' alias db_env='. /home/oracle/db_env'
> But When i wrote on  terminal `[oracle@merkez-rac1 ~]$ echo
> $ORACLE_HOME`
>
>
> [oracle@merkez-rac1 ~]$  It give  me nothing  and dosent show me the
> directory  /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell what the question is, but if it's about ORACLE_HOME, try putting a newline in on that line:

```
ORACLE_HOME=$DB_HOME; export ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_SID=RAC1; export
ORACLE_SID ORACLE_TERM=xterm; export ORACLE_TERM
```

should be

```
ORACLE_HOME=$DB_HOME; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=RAC1; export ORACLE_SID
ORACLE_TERM=xterm; export ORACLE_TERM
```

and so on